# Gap between image and text when floating image to right of text

Tags: html, css

Using the float property the second image (next to development section) has a large gap between it and the text. I need it to have the same spacing as the first image (next to the design section) The `.development` class is for the second image. `skills-row` class is the div.

```css
.design {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.development {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0
}

.skill-row {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="design pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="editor image">
    <h3 class="design-header">Design</h3>
    <p>Focusing on the design and message you want to convey.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="development pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="earth leaf image">
    <h3>Development</h3>
    <p>Develop that initial idea so that we create a website that runs across multiple devices.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting the second image to have the same distance from the text as the first image. But there's a much larger gap between the first image and the text.

Comment: Can you please show the related HTML code part

Comment: I should add that this issue is only apparent when viewing the web page full screen

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be a number of things. In the future, this question would be easier to answer if you posted a `https://codepen.io/pen/`. Some general tips though:

1. If you want the same look, use the same class. You have:

`class="design pic"`
`class="development pic"`

These have different styling, so you're going to get different results.
One has `padding-right: 30px;` and the other has `margin-left: 0`. Make one class, and assign them both that class, and you'll get the same design.

As well, you're floating these images. This means the images will 'float' to the left or right of your div. Maybe the space is actually due to the text being short, and your image floating.

2. You seem to have extraneous classes. Why do they both have class `pic`, but there is no `.pic` in your stylesheet? This should be the class that you use for both and assign both the same style.
3. You have a text with invariable lengths. If you want the images to function the same, I'd suggest you also require the text to have similar constraints.

I hope this helps!

UPDATE
There are other ways to get an image left and right. For example - move the `img` after the `h3` and `p` where you want it on the right.

Comment: _"In the future, this question would be easier to answer if you posted a https://codepen.io/pen/"_ Please don't recommend that as it's unnecessary and goes against SO best practices. Anyone can create a stack snippet in the question which is executable just like on codepen or jsFiddle, yet where links to those service can rot or be blocked, the embedded snippet won't go away.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the response. I've amended the styles to match my classes. I can't assign them to the same class as I need one image to float left and the other to float right. The text is shorter on the image of the computer screen but it still aligns fine. I just can't seem to resolve the issue of the gap between the text and image of the earth. I've tried amending the padding on the text and the image it doesn't work. It's only when I view the page full screen that the gap issue occurs.

Comment: @j08691 it's 'unnecessary' ?? - it's more helpful than just posting css and html. If there's another way, okay, but to say it's unnecessary is ridiculous.

Comment: @orangejuice Honestly, I can't see what you're seeing. The best way with something simple like HTML and CSS is to post a working example. I made an update to my answer though. I still think the answer lies in the fact that you're styling both images differently, according to your CSS.

Comment: Yes it's unnecessary to request a codepen or jsFiddle when the same functionality can be put into the question itself as a runnable example. There's no need to have people visit a third part off-site resource.